# Package body created with compilation error due to Function body in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, package

I am using Oracle 10g Express edition.

Here is my Package creation code:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ticketBooking 
   AS 
      PROCEDURE bookOrder(id IN NUMBER, key IN VARCHAR2, fname IN VARCHAR2, lname IN VARCHAR2, age IN NUMBER, address IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, status OUT NUMBER);
      PROCEDURE bookTicket(id IN NUMBER, orderID IN NUMBER, mID IN NUMBER, mRow IN NUMBER, mSeat IN NUMBER, mDate IN VARCHAR2, mTime IN NUMBER, status OUT NUMBER);
      FUNCTION maxOrderID RETURN NUMBER; 
      FUNCTION maxTransactionID RETURN NUMBER;
   END ticketBooking; 
/
```

Now, here is the Package body creation:-

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ticketBooking
    IS
        PROCEDURE 
        bookOrder (id IN NUMBER, key IN VARCHAR2, fname IN VARCHAR2, lname IN VARCHAR2, age IN NUMBER, address IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, status OUT NUMBER) 
        IS
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_order (order_id, order_key, order_fname, order_lname, order_age, order_address, order_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, key, fname, lname, age, address, TO_DATE(adate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
            status := 1;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            status := 0;
          END bookOrder;

        PROCEDURE 
        bookTicket (id IN NUMBER, orderID IN NUMBER, mID IN NUMBER, mRow IN NUMBER, mSeat IN NUMBER, mDate IN VARCHAR2, mTime IN NUMBER, status OUT NUMBER)
        IS
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (transaction_id, order_id, movie_id, movie_row, movie_seat, movie_date, movie_time) 
            VALUES ( id, orderID, mID, mRow, mSeat, mDate, mTime);
            status := 1;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            status := 0;
          END bookTicket;

        FUNCTION 
        maxOrderID RETURN NUMBER
        IS
          mOID NUMBER:=0;
          BEGIN
            SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(order_id) > 0 THEN MAX(order_id) ELSE 0 END INTO mOID FROM tbl_order;
            return (mOID);
          END maxOrderID; 

        FUNCTION 
        maxTransactionID RETURN NUMBER 
        IS
          mTID NUMBER:=0;
          BEGIN
            SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(transaction_id) > 0 THEN MAX(transaction_id) ELSE 0 END INTO mTID FROM tbl_transaction;
            return (mTID);
          END maxTransactionID;

    END ticketBooking;
/
```

I am getting an error that Package Body created with compilation error.
What am I doing wrong?
When I am removing the functions, that time no warning or compilation error is shown.

Comment: If you do `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view, you can see what the actual compilation errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing:

- return clause of the functions. Add `return number`
- `then` and `end if` in the `if`s

Try this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY ticketBooking
    IS
        PROCEDURE 
        bookOrder (id IN NUMBER, key IN VARCHAR2, fname IN VARCHAR2, lname IN VARCHAR2, age IN NUMBER, address IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, status OUT NUMBER) 
        IS
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_order (order_id, order_key, order_fname, order_lname, order_age, order_address, order_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, key, fname, lname, age, address, TO_DATE(adate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
            status := 1;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            status := 0;
          END bookOrder;

        PROCEDURE 
        bookTicket (id IN NUMBER, orderID IN NUMBER, mID IN NUMBER, mRow IN NUMBER, mSeat IN NUMBER, mDate IN VARCHAR2, mTime IN NUMBER, status OUT NUMBER)
        IS
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (transaction_id, order_id, movie_id, movie_row, movie_seat, movie_date, movie_time) 
            VALUES ( id, orderID, mID, mRow, mSeat, mDate, mTime);
            status := 1;
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            status := 0;
          END bookTicket;

        FUNCTION 
        maxOrderID return number
        IS
          mOID NUMBER:=0;
          dReturn NUMBER:=0; 
          BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(order_id) INTO mOID FROM tbl_order;
            if(mOID > 0) then
               return (mOID);
            else
               return (dReturn);   
              end if;
          END maxOrderID; 

        FUNCTION 
        maxTransactionID return number
        IS
          mTID NUMBER:=0;
          dReturn NUMBER:=0; 
          BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(transaction_id) INTO mTID FROM tbl_transaction;
            if(mTID > 0) then
               return (mTID);
            else
               return (dReturn);   
              end if;
          END maxTransactionID;

    END ticketBooking;
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please can you help me a bit?

Comment: @Saswat, you need to tell us what the compilation errors are - we can't see your screen.